# Making a game where you click a circle and a new one appears but can't figure out how to make the circle a button

Tags: java

I'm quite new to JAVA and still learning and can't figure out **how to make the location of my button iCirclePosX and iCirclePosY and make it shaped the same as the circle** (The button redraws the circle) I'm fairly sure I have to use something other than BorderLayout but I don't know how it works and would like some assistance. Thanks!

```
package stackover;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import static java.lang.Math.random;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import so61997395.Board;
import so61997395.Circle;
import so61997395.Game;




/**
 *
 * @author 18086
 */

public class PaintFrame extends JFrame {
    public static int iCircleSize() {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    }

    public static int iCirclePosX() {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 750 + 1);
    }

    public static int iCirclePosY() {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 750 + 1);
    }

    private JPanel content = new JPanel();
    private JButton drawButton = new JButton("Draw");
    private PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

    public PaintFrame() {
        getContentPane().add(content);
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        drawButton.setSize(100, 500);
        drawButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // drawButton is fired, repaint the paintPanel
                paintPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        content.add(drawButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        content.add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintFrame().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        int iSize = iCircleSize();
        PaintPanel board = new PaintPanel();
        board.add(new Circle(iCirclePosX(), iCirclePosY(), new 
            Dimension(iSize+100, iSize+100)));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setContentPane(board);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    PaintPanel() {
        super(null);
    }

    public void PaintPanel() {
        setSize(750, 750);
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }
}   

class Circle extends JComponent {

    Circle(int x, int y, Dimension size) {
        setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), size));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                paintPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 

        // draw 5 random circles 
        int count = 1;
        PaintPanel repaintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your title ask to "make the circle a button" while your question is about positioning the circles. What do you want ?

Comment: I'd like both, the circle to be a button (or a button ontop of it shaped like a circle) and make the poistion follow the circle painted by the paint component

Answer (score 3):

**To have a clickable circle**

One possibility will be to create a subclass of `Jbutton` and override the `paint` method to draw a circle. But that will lead to many other issues.

Another one will be to maintains a collection of all drawn circles and listen for the mouse click on the container panel to see if the mouse was clicked on a button.

Yet anther solution (the one that I will choose) would be to create a custom component that paint the circle and listen for mouse click.

**To position your circles**

The best layout will be `null`. With a `null` layout you have an absolute layout where components are positioned according to their bounds : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

---

*Edit; Add sample code*

```
package so61997395;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Board board = new Board();
        board.add(new Circle(150, 80, new Dimension(30, 30)));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setContentPane(board);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Board extends JPanel {
    Board() {
        super(null);
    }
}

class Circle extends JComponent {
   Circle(int x, int y, Dimension size) {
        setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), size));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                move();
            }
        });
    }

    private void move() {
        Container board = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JPanel.class, this);
        setLocation(new Point(
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(board.getWidth()),
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(board.getHeight())
        ));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the third solution please.

Comment: I just edited my code above and have almost worked it out but can't get the onclick event to repaint the panel

Comment: There are some issues in your code. But why do you say that you can't get the onclick event to repaint the panel ? His content is never changed so you may not notice the repaint.

Comment: I'm trying to get it so when i click the circle it repaints it elsewhere. How do I make my code do that?

Comment: Then either remove the `Circle`, then create and add a new one. Or create a method on the `Circle` to change his location.

Comment: I have edited my sample code with the "moving circle". Calling `setLocation` on the `Circle` cause a repaint on his parent.